# Best way to integrate sound into website

Tags: audio

I am looking to integrate sound into a website. Basically a chat website where users will hear a sound when a new message arrives. What do you think is the best way to integrate sound?

1. Javascript to play the sound
2. Javascript to call a flash swf which plays the sound
3. Any other method I cant think of?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just make sure you give users the option to disable this feature. Many would find it annoying.

Comment: as RichardOD says, make sure people can disable it. People don't expect websites to make sounds, and are often very annoyed by it (I know I am).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A small swf with the sound controlled by javascript would the the way to go in terms of being cross platform and cross browser.

Comment: swf's are definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with option #2. But, with a word of caution when integrating any sound into a web site, people often find it annoying, when a sound comes out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

As Conrad said, use javascript and swf. You can also take a look at what other people use. One example that I like is the [Campfire](http://campfirenow.com/) chat. It works in all browsers and OS:es that I've tried it with.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution would be to use the upcoming HTML5 `<audio>` tag. You can script this from JavaScript. Support for this is poor, however.

As as said by others, the alternative would be a Flash solution.

I would recommend using the `<audio>` tag where possible and Flash as fallback content.

Comment: What browsers support HTML5 currently?

Comment: IE 8, FF3.5, Chrome and Safari 4 all support *some* HTML5. I think only Safari and FF do the audio tags at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like websites that need JavaScript activated to accomplish something in Flash (eg. youtube), because generally speaking I have deactivated JavaScript. Therefore I would suggest to only use Flash. However this is a personal thing. Most users probably don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like background music or sounds on websites. Reminds me of the bad old days were every site had a background MIDI file on it.

At least have the option to switch it off :)

Answer (score 0):

## 3 Use Flash. It's widely supported and it works better than Java applets.

Please make a clearly visible mute button too! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very nice API that uses flash and javascript to make embedding sound in your webpages easy as something very easy: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the ethics of whether to make a sound play in a web page automatically...

I've got this working with XHTML 1.0 Strict in FF 3.x+, Opera 9.x+, IE6+, but not in Chrome (3.0.195.38) or Safari (4.0.4). So, I can't figure out how to get Webkit to accept it. Note this likely **will not pass XHTML validation**. And also note that my doctype stuff starts off like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Anyway, although the following code doesn't work yet in Webkit browsers, it works in other browsers:

```
<bgsound src="http://example.com/sound.wav" loop="0" />
<audio src="http://example.com/sound.wav" autoplay loop="false" />
```

If anyone know how to get this working in Webkit browsers, I'd like to know how.