# alert beep sound new user comes

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver, beep

i am doing private chat concept. i want to alert beep sound when new user comes in. how to do? i am displaying every thing when new user comes in user details will comes at admin side. but at the same i want to alert beep sound when new user comes.

Comment: Is this on the web, or a desktop application? What language? What framework? Etc, etc. To help you, we need more information.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am doing this using php,mysql. wamp server.

Comment: We need a lot more information than that to give accurate help.

Comment: fine....i am doing live chat application using php,mysql and using wamp server. in this users chat  with admin. users who are chating with admin all users names displaying at admin side. at the same i want to alert beep sound when suddenly new user comes in to chat console.

Comment: Not sure any of those keywords have any relevance; at least, PHP and mysql have nothing to do with making a beep :)

Comment: so how to make an alert...is there any another choice..for what to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to integrate sound into website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000263/best-way-to-integrate-sound-into-website)

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the new [`<audio />`](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/) tag for html5 and then provide a fallback for non-html5 browsers.

Comment: i have no idea about this. plz give me any reference

Answer (score 1):

In *unix you can run an simple command in shell < https://www.php.net/exec > like this:

xmms file.mp3

or redirect some file to /dev/interface_of_sound